# simple calculator in c++ weird results

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ 
I tried to create a simple calculator.
I am not sure why but when I run this code, it prints weird results, for example: 15 * 5 = 753

```
        int a;
        int b;
        char param;
        printf("Enter Two numbers:\n");
        scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
        printf("Enter mathematical operator *-/+\n");
        int result;
        scanf_s(" %c", &param);
        switch (param)
        {
        case ('+'):
            result = a + b;
            printf("%d", result);
        case ('-'):
            result = a - b;
            printf("%d", result);
        case ('*'):
            result = a * b;
            printf("%d", result);
        case ('/'):
            result = a / b;
            printf("%d", result);
        }
```

Comment: btw you are not using any c++ in your code. In particular `scanf_s` is not standard C++ afaik. The `_s` functions are a useful addition to C, but in C++ they arent really necessary because we have `std::string`, msvc offers them in C++ as an extension

Comment: Nothing weird to see here. It is doing exactly what you wrote. (next time include the output and your expected output, we can only guess now). Also listen to idclev you aren't using C++ so either you mistagged it or you're not using C++ but C

Comment: Also remove the space in `" %c"` (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no break between cases which explain that your example enter in case '*' print 75 (15 * 5) as there is no break continue to '/' and print 3 (15 / 5). And that's what you got 753.

```
switch (param)
{
case ('+'):
    result = a + b;
    printf("%d", result);
    break;
case ('-'):
    result = a - b;
    printf("%d", result);
    break;
case ('*'):
    result = a * b;
    printf("%d", result);
    break;
case ('/'):
    result = a / b;
    printf("%d", result);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember to [include `break;` statement](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/08/cpp-switch-case/) after each `case`

```
    int a;
    int b;
    char param;
    printf("Enter Two numbers:\n");
    scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b);
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    printf("Enter mathematical operator *-/+\n");
    int result;
    scanf_s(" %c", &param);
    switch (param)
    {
    case ('+'):
        result = a + b;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    case ('-'):
        result = a - b;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    case ('*'):
        result = a * b;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    case ('/'):
        result = a / b;
        printf("%d\n", result);
        break;
    }
```

---

[Working code](https://ideone.com/QIZkBq)